# Spring data mongo db group by _class

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Maybe anybody knows how to group collection by _class field.

I have many documents with different _class fields and I want to group them:

```
{
   type1: [docs],
   type2: [docs],
   ...
   typen: [docs]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `Map` of some sort.

Comment: I have a collection with different types of documents. For instance: [{_class: "type1"}, {_class: "type2"}] and I'd like to group these documents by _class field.

Comment: I could do something like that: db.colName.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$_class", docs: {$addToSet: "$$ROOT"}}}
]), but in the result I got the array instead of object with key and values. How to concat the group result to one single json object?